# Re-selecting from a table based on query results

Tags: mysql, sql, select

my sql knowledge is fairly basic and I would be grateful for some advice. I have a table with columns like:

date, time, readings, .... comments1, comments2

What I would like to do is filter the table to show the results when comments1 is equal to a string, which I can achieve. The tricky bit is I then want to find the readings when the time is between 5 and 7 hours after the times returned/identified by the initial query (comments1 = string"). Is there a way to do this with and what would be the best strategy?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your WHERE clause needs an AND in it.  For example: `WHERE comments1 = 'STRING' AND (time >= 5 AND time <= 7)`

Answer (score 1):

You should really store date and time in a single column, otherwise midnight boundaries are extremely difficult to select across. My example assumes your "date" column is a `datetime` type that also stores the timestamp.

I believe something like this is what you're looking for:

```
WITH CommentTime AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 date
    FROM tblRecords
    WHERE comments1 = 'The comment to find'
)
SELECT *
FROM tblRecords
WHERE date >= DATEADD(hour, 5, (SELECT date FROM CommentTime))
  AND date < DATEADD(hour, 7, (SELECT date FROM CommentTime))
```

Answer (score 0):

New Answer: 
(Reworking Dans answer to instead use a variable)

```
DECLARE @CommentTime AS DateTime = (SELECT TOP 1 [date] FROM tblRecords WHERE comments1 = 'string')
SELECT * FROM tblRecords 
WHERE [date] >= DATEADD(HOUR, 5, @CommentTime)
  AND [date] < DATEADD(HOUR, 7, @CommentTime)
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking for. Read it again.

Comment: I see now, the way it was worded confused me.

Comment: If you improve your answer I'll happily change my vote.

Comment: Just changed my answer, took a spin on yours as there wasn't too many other ways to spin this question.

Comment: Yeah, if he's using a stored procedure a temp var would be more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and sorry about the wording. Would the above two still work if there was more than one result with the desired string?

Comment: Well, for this answer we are assuming one result with the specified string will be used as the base for the date in the following select. If the date is the same on all of the matching results with the desired string, there would be no difference, however, if you want all of the values between 5 and 7 hours which is inclusive of every date where the specific comment is "x" then the query will need to be a bit more complex.

Comment: how might one go about achieving the latter?